# circlize in R to make a circular plot

Tags: r, plot, package, geometry, circlize

Im trying to make a circular plot similar to gene expression plots.
I found the circlize package in R could do this, and Im trying to follow this http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circlize/vignettes/genomic_plot.pdf

I manage to get to: 6. Create plotting regions

But when I type

```
circos.genomicPoints(Region, value, numeric.column = c(1,2))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in get.cell.meta.data("sector.index") : 
Length of `sector.index` should only be 1.
```

And when I type

```
circos.genomicLines(Region, value, numeric.column = c(1, 2))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in region[[1]] + region[[2]] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Region is a data frame with 205 observations and 7 variables: chromosome, start position, end position, and then some values
value is a data frame with 205 observations and 2 variables: both numeric values

Im completely new to this kind of plot, so any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You need to supply more detail.  Did everything up to that point plot correctly?  Did you build the functions exactly as written in Section 6?

Comment: Yes, everything up to that point worked and plotted correctly

Comment: Since the referenced vignette does not supply `data` or `region`, (not to mention that multiple warnings and errors popped up as I executed the code provided), there may be errors in the vignette and/or the way you built your  own `region` .

Answer (score 2):

`region` in low-level functions such as `circos.genomicPoints` or `circos.genomicLines` should be a data frame which only contains two columns (start positions and end positions). Because functions such as `circos.genomicPoints` only work for one chromosome at a time, it is not necessary to put chromosome information in the `region`.

A recommended way to call `circos.genomicPoints` is to put into `panel.fun` when calling `circos.genomicTrackPlotRegion`:

```
bed  # your data frame which is bed-file format
circos.initializeWithIdeogram()
circos.genomicTrackPlotRegion(bed, panel.fun = function(region, value, ...) {
    circos.genomicPoints(region, value, ...)
})
```

In above example code, `panel.fun` is a self-defined function which will be executed in every chromosome. `region` and `value` in `panel.fun` are corresponding data frames in 'current chromosome' that are extracted from `bed`.

If you want to fine-tune your plot by calling `circos.genomicPoints` outside `circos.genomicTrackPlotRegion`, you need to construct your `region` and `value` variables and also don't forget to set `sector.index` or `track.index` to specify which chromosome and which track you want to put the graphics:

```
for(chr in chromosomes) {
    region = bed[bed[[1]] == "chr", 2:3]
    value = bed[bed[[1]] == "chr", some_column_index]
    circos.genomicPoints(region, value, sector.index = chr, ...)
}
```

Comment: Btw, some example code in 'genomic_plot.pdf' vignette is just for demonstration while cannot be executed. It is because drawing a genomic-level plot always needs more chunk of code, if putting all the code in the vignette, it will look terrible. The use of genomic circos functions are quite similar as use of general circos functions, they have the same idea behind. It's better for users to read main vignette (circlize.pdf) first. Also users can go to [http://jokergoo.github.io/circlize/](http://jokergoo.github.io/circlize/) for executable examples.